# Jquery animate not running second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a progress bar in form of a circle. The first time it runs smoothly from 0% to 40%. When I update a value (ex. +10%) the progress bar goes from 40% to 50%, but not smoothly, it goes directly, not mather what duration time I set. So the functionality is working but not the animation on the second run. I'm really thankfull for any tips/pointers. How come it doesnt animate the progress in the second (or third, fourth) run?

I update the new value and then call the function with:

```
$(this).UpdateCircle('zero');
```

Function:

```
//startmode = 'start' (from 0) or 'current' (from current value)
$.fn.extend({
UpdateCircle: function (startmode='') {

        var $original = $(this);

        var percentage = parseFloat(($(this).data('count')/$(this).data('totalcount'))*100);

        if(startmode=='zero') { var startvalue = 0; durationtime = 1500; }
        else { var startvalue = percentage; var durationtime = 2500; }

        $({value: startvalue}).animate({value: percentage }, {
            duration: durationtime,
            easing:'swing',
            step: function() 
            {
                $original.val(Math.ceil(this.value)).trigger('change');
            }
        });
}
});
```